# how to grep with multiple strings to find

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I understand how to use grep in the simple form:

```
<command that spits out text> | grep "text to find"
```

I would like to be able to `grep` multiple different bits of text all at once.
How do I do that? Is `grep` the correct command to do this?

### Example

I run `arp-scan` and I get a list of devices and their mac addresses. I want to search for the presence of multiple unique mac address strings. If I only wanted 1 mac address, I would use `grep` like this:

```
arp-scan --localnet --interface=<my interface> | grep "mac address"
```

I have heard of `sed`, but I don't know if it fits my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `grep` for this. And there are several approaches, look [here, for example](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/grep-multiple-strings):

1. Use the escaped pipe symbol in the expression:

   ```
   <command that spits out text> | grep "text to find\|another text to find"
   ```
2. Use `grep` with the `-E` option:

   ```
   <command that spits out text> | grep -E "text to find|another text to find"
   ```
3. Use `grep` with `-e` options:

   ```
   <command that spits out text> | grep -e "text to find" -e "another text to find"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this

1. pass multiple patterns with `-e` ex.

   ```
   somecommand | grep -e foo -e bar -e baz
   ```
2. use a *regular expression* that matches multiple patterns ex. using the *extended regular expression* alternation operator `|`

   ```
   somecommand | grep -E 'foo|bar|baz'
   ```
3. put the patterns one-per-line in a file, and pass the file to `grep` via the `-f` option ex.

   ```
   somecommand | grep -f patfile
   ```

   where

   ```
   $ cat patfile
   foo
   bar
   baz
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to grep multiline after your query string, you can use it

```
grep -A 3 "your query string" your_file
```

`3` is the line number you want to see after your condition.

Line number after your query: `-A NUM, --after-context=NUM`

Line number before your query: `-B NUM, --before-context=NUM`

Remember you can always use `-i` option to ignore case-sensitively
`your_first_command | grep -i 'your query string' 'your file_name'`